# What happened to Chromes warning about Distrusting Symantec Certificates?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, symantec

For a while our website gave the following warning in the console:

[image]

Today I wanted to check to see if I could fix it but it seems to have disappeared. I can't find anything about that message disappearing though. Did google and Symantex sort out their differences?

What happened here?

Answer (score 0):

The tense is changed from future to present perfect.

> The SSL certificate used to load resources from <URL> has been distrusted. See https://g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for more information.
>
> GET <URL> net::ERR_CERT_SYMANTEC_LEGACY

This is still here in Chrome 70 beta (stable in October); it was briefly in Firefox 63 beta but was pushed back to Firefox 64 (stable in December).

These articles are still up to date:

- https://security.googleblog.com/2018/03/distrust-of-symantec-pki-immediate.html
- https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2018/10/10/delaying-further-symantec-tls-certificate-distrust/

If this resource was loaded from a server that you do not control, then I would imagine that they updated their certificate.